# Okta Api C# filtering options

Tags: c#, linq, okta, okta-api

I am trying to use the OKTA API in C# to get user information. The filtering options seem extremely basic and trying to filter out after the fact is very slow using something like LINQ.

I find the OKTA documentation extremely hard to follow or to actually find anything useful.

Is there some other way to query OKTA in C# where you can get a smaller subset of users before having to use some other filtering method?

Is there a way to use the filtering by login where it doesn't require absolute case sensitivity in login name being used?

I feel like either I am missing something here or the options are just so few the API is semi-useless.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking a look at the [Okta C# SDK](https://github.com/okta/oktasdk-csharp). It uses the `FilterBuilder` class to return a subset of users.

For case insensitive searches, try using the [Find Users](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#find-users) API call.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://{{ORG_URL}}/api/v1/users?q={{QUERY}}");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("authorization", "SSWS {{API_TOKEN}}");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```